# Drupal 7 Filefield Paths upload settings page

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7, filefield

I'm new to Drupal and am trying to configure the upload path settings of Filefield paths so that images and files are uploaded into a folder based on their node type.  I have things setup the way I like for custom fields, but can't seem to find the upload settings page for the core fields (body in particular).

The [module info page](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) says that the upload path settings are found under Workflow settings > Upload Path Settings, or `http://[www.yoursite.com/path/to/drupal]/admin/content/node-type/[node-type]`, but those links seem to have changed for D7.  Can anyone point me to the D7 settings page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is now set up for each individual file upload field. In order to modify the settings for that particular file upload, you simply go to:

http://example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/node-type/fields/field-name/

(replace node-type with article/blog/etc and field-name with field_image or whatever your custom field is)

Assuming the module is installed, there should then be a section called *Image Path Settings*